# Access Redshift (within a VPC) from Data Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a Redshift database hosted within a VPC. I am building an AWS Data Pipeline but when I try to connect to the Redshift database I am unable to:

```
[ERROR] (TaskRunnerService-resource:XXX) amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory: 
Unable to establish connection to jdbc:redshift://XXXX:5439/dev 
[Amazon](500150) Error setting/closing connection: Connection timed out.
```

Is there any way to access Redshift (within a VPC) from AWS Data Pipeline? What do I need to change to the VPC settings to allow Data Pipeline to access it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Eventually* working it out, you need to go to the EC2 console and get the IP address of the spawned instanced that is created when you run Data Pipeline. You then need to add that IP to the "Inbound" tab of your VPC's ACL and security groups.

Comment: I ve this problem right now but i would like a better solution since this will only only work on the first run